# Getting command output from Linux hosts

Tags: c#, .net, linux, ssh, process

My requirement is to write a C# program to display process output, restart failed process (which runs with power broker role accounts).

I went through few QA in this site already and I could see discussions of using SharpSSH, etc.. but since I work in a highly secured environment and downloading third party software is a breach of compliance. Is this SharpSSH accepted as a freeware and can be downloaded ? - I guess no.

So what other option do we have ? - I am happy to spend sometime reading documents or wiki page to understand and get this to work. Currently I am in no man's land, confused on where to start. Can someone help me out ?.

Thank you

Comment: Use TCP which will run on both Linux and windows.  Telnet uses tcp so you can open a telnet session on the Linux machine and then redirect stdinput/stdout to a shell jprocess.